# Android: Cannot Resolve Method from custom PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a ViewPager with a custom PagerAdapter. I want to be able to access and modify the fragment that is currently being displayed by the ViewPager. I am getting a compiler error when trying to call a method that I made and put inside a class (from Google dev) that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The method that isn't being recognized outside of the ScreenSlidePagerAdapter class is "getCurrentFragment()". It works inside the class, but not outside.

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int NUM_PAGES;
private Fragment mCurrentFragment;

public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NUM_PAGES) {
    super(fm);
    this.NUM_PAGES = NUM_PAGES;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_PAGES;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new CalendarFragment();
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
        mCurrentFragment = (Fragment) object;
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return mCurrentFragment;
}

}
```

As you can see, it works fine inside the object class itself, but when I call it inside the MainActivity, I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentFragment()'.

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), NUM_PAGES);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    Fragment frag = mPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
```

How do I fix this? Is my approach to getting the currently displayed fragment wrong as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your full code, I can't be sure, but I suspect `mPagerAdapter` is declared incorrectly.

It should be

```
ScreenSlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
```

not

```
FragmentStatePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
```

Comment: Yep that's it. I had PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter; instead of ScreenSlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jellio Glad I could help. I'm afraid I can't help you on your last bit as I don't know about fragments.

Comment: 2 years later, I have to comment you're a wizard, thanks for solving my problem without even reading the code :)